# Non-existence of a dischargeable hypothesis

Tags: quantifiers, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I meet a question about the existence/non-existence of a dischargeable hypothesis. The question is as follows: in intuitionistic logic, if for every proposition $X$, it cannot be the case that $X$ implies $A$ and $X$ is true, does it as a whole implies $\neg A$?

$$(\forall X\neg((X\rightarrow A)\wedge X))\xrightarrow{?}\neg A$$

And what if we add a further condition that $X\not\leftrightarrow A$?

Comment: Specializing to $X=A$ gives $\neg((A\to A)\land A)\eqiv \neg A$. Excluding $X=A$ seems moot, when you can just take something "semi-obviously equivalent" to $A$ instad

Comment: Can you expand on the condition $X \neq A$ a little? Is the equality of propositions extensional so that $(X \neq A) \equiv \neg (X \leftrightarrow A)$? Or are syntactically distinct propositions considered unequal along the lines of Hagen von Eitzen's "semi-obviously equivalent" proposition?

Comment: @SCappella Yes, that's it. I will edit the post to make it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I.** First, let's deal with the case when we are allowed to substitute $A$ for $X$. Then the desired implication holds. The proof is as follows.

Take a proposition $A$ and assume that $\neg ((X \rightarrow A) \wedge X$ holds for all propositions $X$. Assume for a contradiction that $A$ holds.

Clearly $A \rightarrow A$ holds, and by our second assumption $A$ holds as well, so $(A \rightarrow A) \wedge A$ holds. But by our first assumption we also have that $\neg ((A \rightarrow A) \wedge A)$, a contradiction.

Thus, we conclude that if $\neg ((X \rightarrow A) \wedge X)$ holds for all propositions $X$, then $\neg A$ holds.

**II.** It's not clear what the restriction $X \neq A$ means here. If it just means that we're not allowed to substitute the specific formula $A$, then that's not really a strong restriction: we could substitute the syntactically different, but practically equivalent formula $A \wedge A$ instead.

But there's another way to interpret $X \neq A$, as the restriction that we must prove $\neg (X \leftrightarrow A)$ for each $X$ that we choose to substitute. Effectively, this just changes our first assumption to  $\forall X. \neg(X \leftrightarrow A) \rightarrow \neg((X \rightarrow A) \wedge A)$. In this case, the implication need not hold (indeed, it does not hold for $A \equiv \top$).

This is because $\neg(X \leftrightarrow A) \rightarrow \neg((X \rightarrow A) \wedge A)$ is a theorem of the intuitionistic second-order calculus for every proposition $X$. Here's a proof:

Let $X$ be arbitrary, and assume $\neg (X \leftrightarrow A)$ and $(X \rightarrow A) \wedge X$. We want to reach a contradiction. To do that, we shall prove $X \leftrightarrow A$. We already have $X \rightarrow A$ by the first conjunct of the second assumption, and since we have $X$ by the second conjunct as well, we can just use $X \rightarrow (A \rightarrow X)$ to conclude $A \rightarrow X$ as well. Thus, $X \leftrightarrow A$, contradicting our first assumption.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer! It's quite clear for me now.

Comment: I find this quite interesting! I have a question, why the formula $\forall X.\neg(X\leftrightarrow A)\rightarrow\neg((X\rightarrow A)\wedge A)$ does not hold for $A\equiv\top$?

Comment: @Kelly Trust your reasoning, you know it holds :)

It's precisely the point that the antecedent of the desired implication, $\forall X.\neg(X\leftrightarrow \top)\rightarrow\neg((X\rightarrow \top)\wedge \top)$ holds, but the consequent of the implication, $\neg \top$, fails. Thus, _the implication fails_ (which is, as far as I can see, precisely what I wrote).